# How can I limit function parameter values?

Tags: c#, enums, parameter-passing

I have a function, that has an enum value as a parameter. In this specific function, I expect the enum value to only be able to have two of the four enum values. Can I limit the expected parameters?

```cs
public enum DifferenceType
{
    Identical,
    Added,
    Changed,
    Removed
}

public void DoSomething(DifferenceType difference)
{
    if( difference == DifferenceType.Added)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else // Assert the value is DifferenceType.Removed
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

I could expect a `bool` like `IsDifferenceTypeAdded` or something like that, but that feels unclean, since it doesn't imply that otherwise it can only be `DifferenceType`. Is there any other way that I'm not thinking of?

The enum is used at different places in our program and I can't change it. This is not a big problem, but I am curious if there is a better way of doing that.

Comment: use another enum which has 2 fields only. Or, {do nothing / throw exception} for unexpected argument.

Comment: You can throw `ArgumentException` if the parameter is invalid, and you can do nothing silently if this is valid in your application logic.

Comment: You can use a more-limited enum for this method, which can take its values from `DifferenceType`: `public enum LimitedDifferenceType { Added = DifferenceType.Added, Removed = DifferenceType.Removed }`. That does mean you have to use that other enum when calling `DoSomething`.

Comment: Instead of the method `DoSomething`, provide 2 methods `void DoSomething_at_Added()` and `void DoSomething_at_Removed()` (as no argument method).

Comment: @fana thank you, I did just that, that seems like a good way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There's isn't a magic bullet to solve this problem. Specifically, in the case you're describing (and without further knowledge of your actual system, of course) I would probably rather do what fana suggested in the comments and simply have a method for each supported types:

```
public void DoSomethingOnAdd() {/* implementation */}

public void DoSomethingOnRemove() {/* implementation */}
```

but in a more general way, suppose you have an enum with 40 members instead of just 4, and you want the method to handle, say, 10 of these members.
In this case, I would consider creating another enum just for this method, and
add an extension method to your main enum, to translate from it to the new enum - something like this:

```
public enum SupportedType
{
    Unsupported, Added, Removed
}

static class DifferenceTypeExtensions
{
    public static SupportedType ToSupportedType(this DifferenceType dt)
        => dt switch
        {
            DifferenceType.Added => SupportedType.Added,
            DifferenceType.Removed => SupportedType.Removed,
            _ => SupportedType.Unsupported
        };
 }
```

and then in your method just use the `SupportedType` enum:

```
public void DoSomething(SupportedType difference)
{
    if(difference == SupportedType.Added)
    {
        // do something
    }
     if(difference == SupportedType.Removed)
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Note that you might want to remove the `Unsupported` member and replace it with throwing an exception, but that really depends on your actual use-case.

If you expect others to call this method with inappropriate values, you should probably not use an exception but simply perform no action - because exceptions should be used for exceptional situations, but then again, that really does depend on your use case.